# Inserting series into a new dataframe column for each group of a groupby object

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Apologies in advance if the question is too simple. I'm calculating vessel speeds, grouped by their mmsi identifier, and for each pair of consecutive rows. For this, I have a function that returns a series containing the speeds. I want to insert the speeds into a new column of the original dataframe in their corresponding position.

For example, for `mmsi = 1`, the function returns `[nan, 15]`, for `mmsi = 2`, `[nan, 19, 8]`, and for `mmsi = 3`, `[nan, 19, 8, 15]`

```
timestamp    mmsi lat  lon  speed
    
0.2          1    4.7  3.2  nan
0.5          1    2.3  5.6  15
0.1          2    9.3  8.4  nan
0.6          2    8.3  9.2  19
0.8          2    6.1  2.3  8
0.2          3    1.5  9.4  nan
0.4          3    8.3  9.2  19
0.6          3    6.1  2.3  8
0.8          3    2.3  5.6  15
```

I have tried this but I haven't figured out how to make it work correctly:

```
def speed(lons, lats, timestamps):

     #Calculates speed
     ...
     ...
     ...
    speed_knots = speed_knots.tolist()      
    return speed_knots


df = pd.read_csv('filtered.csv')
df = df[df.duplicated('mmsi',keep=False)] #Drops rows without duplicated mmsi
df['unix_datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'],unit='s') #Converts Unix format to datetime

df['speed_knots'] = df.groupby('mmsi').apply(lambda x: speed(x.lon,x.lat,x.unix_datetime))
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You function should return a `Series`:

```
def speed(lons, lats, timestamps, index):
    #Calculates speed
    speed_knots = speed_knots.tolist()      
    return pd.Series(speed_knots, index=index)

df['speed_knots'] = (df.groupby('mmsi', group_keys=False)
                       .apply(lambda x: speed(x.lon, x.lat, x.timestamp; x.index))
                     )
```

Comment: 'index=index' gives NameError: name 'index' is not defined. Not sure if I have to put something different instead of the second 'index'...

Comment: Did you add `x.index` in the function call like I did?

Answer (score 1):

You can create the new column in the group

```py
def speed(g):
    lons, lats, timestamps = g.lon,g.lat,g.unig_datetime

    #Calculates speed
    speed_knots = speed_knots.tolist() 

    g = g.assign(speed_knots=speed_knots)
    # or
    g['speed_knots'] = speed_knots

    return g

out = df.groupby('mmsi', group_keys=False).apply(speed)
```